# dict.get(x,y) always evaluates the right hand argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

try this:

```
d = {"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}
d.get("Two", Print("Fail"))
```

Expected Output:

> > 2

Actual Output:

> > Fail
> >
> > 2

Anyone know why the right hand argument of this expression is eagerly evaluated?  What's the point of processing the right hand argument if there's a chance it's not returned?

Is there a logic to this I'm missing?

Comment: In general with programming languages, the parameters to functions (methods) are all evaluated before the function begins. The actual output would be expected in any language.

Comment: Because this is how Python always works. This isn't always the case for every language, e.g. languages that support call by name. But that isn't python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always evaluated because any functions has to be resolved *before* the return value can be sent to `get`.

Instead, you supply a default *value* to use if the key is not present, or if you need to check multiple keys to get a value, the `get` call will return `None`:

```
val = d.get("Two")

if val is None:
    print("Fail..")
```

This is similar to:

```
if 'Two' not in d:
    print("Fail..")
```

If you don't want to provide a default value, the first example can still be useful if you have multiple possible values to check - chaining `.get` calls or having multiple `if .. is None: ..` checks all the way down.

Comment: Ah, duh - stoopid question on my part.  You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lazy evaluation, you should use the `or` operator

```
d = {"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}
d.get("Two") or (print("Fail"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic.

```py
x = d.get("b", expensiveComputation())
```

This is computed like so:

- Compute `"b"`, its value is the first argument to `.get`.
- Call `expensiveComputation()`, its value is the second argument to `.get`.
- Call `.get` with these two arguments
- Assign the returned value to `x`.

If you want short-circuiting, Python is very ergonomic.

```py
x = d.get("a") or expensiveComputation()
```

This is computed like so:

- Compute `"a"`, its value is the first and only argument to `.get`.
- Call `.get` with the one argument.
- Since it's an `or` operator which requires Booleans, call `bool()` on the returned value.
- *If* the result is `True`, use the value returned by `.get`, *else* call `expensiveComputation()`, and use the value returned by it.
- Assign that to `x`.

Of course, not only `None` is falsy, so are empty lists, empty strings, etc; if such falsy objects may occur among your values, this is not what you want.

Python 3.8 [introduces assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) so that you could still write one-liners like so:

```py
x if ((x := d.get("a")) is not None) else expensiveComputation()
```

Here `expensiveComputation()` will only run if `d` does not have a value for `"a"`. But this arguably balances on the verge of unreadable.